# css, js and img files can not be found in asp.net 5 mvc

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to explore Visual Studio 2015 and ASP.NET-5  MVC-6.

Project directory structure-

[image]

Razor view HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <link href="~/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    
      ... ... ...
   </head>
   <body>
     ... ... ...
   </body>
</html>
```

Browser finds no asset files. Screenshot-

[image]

What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `assets` folder should be moved under `wwwroot`.

In ASP.NET 5 all static files go under `wwwroot`.  You can also use a [Grunt](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/using-grunt.html) or [Gulp](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/using-gulp.html) to pre-process files from your project and then place them here.